# Phonegap repeating background local notifications

Tags: cordova, plugins, notifications, local

[This Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) provides a neat way to schedule repeating background local notifications - at least on Android.  The bit of the [documentation](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling) I do not understand is this - the `every` attribute can be a string or a number.  I want to set up local notifications that repeat at 10 minute intervals.  I thought I would try `every:600`.

```
var dd = new Date();
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
text: "Delayed Notification",
firstAt: dd,
every: 600}, localNote);
```

where

```
function localNote(){navigator.notification.beep(2);}
```

However, this does not work - OTH every:"minute" produces minutely beeps.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through the code I see that if you pass in a number they multiply it by 60000, so I'm assuming they're expecting you to pass in the number as minutes, try passing in 10. Actually, the docs also state this:

> That can be a value of minutes or one of `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `week`, `month` or `year`

The code that I'm talking about is here: [parseInterval](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/src/android/notification/Options.java#L120).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well spotted!  Thanks a lot.